# Sent Bitcoin Cash to a Bitcoin address

Tags: bitcoin-cash, segregated-witness, cross-chain-recovery, bitgo

By mistake I have sent BCH to my BTC address in my own wallet. My wallet service is BitGo. I know they have a tool to recover the BCH when they are sent to a non-segwit addresses. I have already tried the tool and the tool gives an error, so I think that my address was a segwit address. BitGo says that when the address is a segwit address:

> Unfortunately, when you sent your transaction, you sent it to a
> Bitcoin address that was using the new Segregated Witness format. As
> this format is not supported on Bitcoin Cash, we cannot recover these
> funds.

Is it possible to have another solution?

Answer (score 3):

Of course it's possible. Since SegWit outputs look like AnyoneCanSpend outputs, you can redeem the outputs.

I can create the redeeming transaction for you, but since transactions with ACS outputs are not relayed, you'll need to find a miner and send your transaction to them, which requires you to e-mail a mining pool owner (No one I've talked to tried this, so I don't know if they will help)

You'll need to check if your SegWit address has spent any Bitcoins. If it hasn't, send the address Bitcoins and spend the Bitcoins from that address.

Maybe you should contact this guy: https://www.reddit.com/r/btc/comments/7g6s9l/an_update_on_bch_segwit_recoveries/

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer, i have controlled the address were i sent the Bitcoin cash and they are there unspent. I will try to contact that guy, but he write that he can help only transaction that are in his sweeping transaction.
I **haven't understand** that: "You'll need to check if your SegWit address has spent any Bitcoins. If it hasn't, send the address Bitcoins and spend the Bitcoins from that address."

Comment: @RaphaelE. The "Witness Program" of the P2SH script must be revealed.

Comment: What if you directly relay those transactions to any mining pool? Will those accept? Or would it have to be some shady miner?

Comment: @Jus12 "Anyone-Can-Spend outputs are currently considered non-standard, and are not relayed on the P2P network. " ([Source](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script#Anyone-Can-Spend_Outputs)) I'm not sure if their software would accept it, but I'm sure that Bitcoin Core will give an error while trying to broadcast it.

Answer (score 3):

On Bitcoin forks that do not support Segwit, outputs that use Wrapped Segwit scripts (P2SH-P2WSH or P2SH-P2WPKH) can in principle be spent by anyone who knows the inner segwit script hash or pubkey hash. This knowledge is not always limited to the owner of the Bitcoin wallet, meaning that third parties can "harvest" these deposits.

While these transactions are consensus-valid, they are nonstandard and will not be relayed in the network. One has to find a miner that includes these transactions directly.

The owner of a Segwit-capable Bitcoin wallet always knows the hash preimage and can construct a recovery transactions. However, since the recovery transaction does not require any signatures, the miner can simply substitute their own destination address. The process therefore requires a trusted miner.

It is also possible for miners to claim these funds without any direct interaction with the wallet owner. When the wallet owner spends a Wrapped Segwit output on the Bitcoin chain, they reveal the hash preimage for that output to the public. Miners on fork coins can monitor the Bitcoin chain for wrapped-segwit spends, cross-reference the spends with matching output scripts on fork coins, and claim these outputs.

Comment: This post looks very insightful, and yet it is very confusing at the same time. I think it could be greatly improved by replacing much of the plain text with links to further and longer and deeper explanations.